# Can't access Windows shared folder

Tags: windows, sharing

I have to sort this out. What's the different between Samba and cifs-utils?

I've done it before without any problem, but now when i click on the Browse network tab i recieve a error message
-Failed to open "/ on ". The specificlocation is not supported.

Im trying to access my shared folder that are shared from my Windows PC, and as i said before, there was no problem earlier when i tried it. But now when i've re-installed Trusty there's no way to even find the Windows PC.

So i've read alot of guides and some say Samba while other say cifs-utils. I've tried them both and non of them works. And yes, i've tried with a correct setup of samba.conf.

Comment: If you update to 18.04, then try this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1088416/13884