# Access Windows 10 Shared Folder from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, file-sharing, shared-folders, lan, transfer

I would like to share files between Windows and Ubuntu.

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I could access shared folder on a Windows machine on my local network my navigating to `Other locations` in Files (Nautilus), accessing the Windows network, and browse. After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, this no longer works for me.

How can I get access to folder shared in Windows 10 from Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Please describe **what** and **how** you shared with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (and Windows).

Comment: We gone to files->Other locations in linux system and  there we could see the windows network. After opening that we could see the windows system there . By clicking on the windows pc we copied the folder from its shared folder.

Comment: @Deciletech Please [edit] your question to add details. It helps to keep the simple Q&A style and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage.

Comment: If you're using a MS account, it will use your email (not displayed username) and password

Answer (score 12):

There was a change in both Windows 10 and Samba.  Some of the details are explained [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390873&p=13764895#post13764895).

The browse by just clicking isn't working, but you can get there by entering the shared folder link in the address field.  Use the server's `IP` address or the `computer name` for the share.  In the example I'm using the IP address of the Windows 10 server:

**Use Keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to type in pathname:**

```
smb://192.168.1.102
```

Typing that in the file browser will bring up authorization prompt.  Use the credentials from your Windows 10 server. This will display all the available shares.  You can then click on the share you want access to.

There are two changes steps you may have to do.  Set `client max protocol = NT1` for the downward compatibility in the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file.  Place the entry just below the **workgroup = WORKGROUP** line.

It should look like this:

```
#======================= Global Settings =======================
[global]

client use spnego = no
client NTLMv2 auth = no

## Browsing/Identification ###
# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   client max protocol = NT1
```

Once you have manually accessed the desired share, you can make it easily accessible in the future by bookmarking it.  You can do this with the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

You can easily rename your bookmarks to something friend and meaningful by right-clicking the name that appears in the File Browser's sidebar.

**Install necessary packages:**

You may have to install `smbclient`, which will ensure you have the necessary dependents such as the `cifs-utils` and the actual `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file.

```
$ sudo apt install smbclient
```

Comment: Works on Lubuntu 18.10 as installed; no additional packages or edits required. Does not support browse by clicking. Works with entering smb://192.168.1.102 in PCManFM-Qt file manager.

Answer (score 2):

On 18.04, I have just had success with the following:

**On Ubuntu:**
Install `smbclient` and add `client max protocol = NT1` to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` as per [L.D. James' answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038770/13884) (see [this post for more info](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384959)).

**On Windows:** Create a folder in Windows to share, e.g. named `shared`.
Make sure the folder is shared: I created a new user on Windows, keeping the `NewUser` name and selected a simple password (I first tried changing the name, but found that change was apparently only skin deep. Perhaps if I had rebooted...). I logged in with `NewUser`, then logged back in with my admin account. I activated network sharing on my private network and for the folder specifically (see e.g. [this post](https://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/)). Then I right clicked the folder and chose `Give access to...`, choosing `NewUser` (you may want additional permissions: see the just linked to post). Under the `Sharing` tab, the folder now has a network path: `//COMPUTERNAME/shared`.

**Still on Windows:**
To gain access to the shared folder, I used the IP of the Windows machine instead of the `COMPUTERNAME`, cf. [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151920/samba-mount-error-could-not-resolve-address-for-xxx-unknown-error).

To find the IP of your Windows machine, right click the network logo, open `Network and Sharing Settings` and choose `Change connection properties`. Take note of the IPv4 near the bottom.

**In Ubuntu:**
Finally, open a terminal on you Ubuntu machine and execute

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=NewUser //[insert IPv4 here]/shared /home/your_ubuntu_username/shared
```

and provide the password for `NewUser` when prompted.

This mounts the shared Windows `shared` folder as a folder `shared` in your Ubuntu user's home directory.

The command is based on suggestions from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151920/samba-mount-error-could-not-resolve-address-for-xxx-unknown-error), where there are also suggestions for storing login credentials.

**I hope it works. Good luck!**

Comment: Rasmus the Great, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I too have had the same issue. Some installations do not download/install cifs-utils by default, even though samba is installed. Here is my smb.conf (relevant sections only)

> ```
> #===========================Global definition=================================
> [global]
> workgroup = WORKGROUP
> client max protocol = NT1
> server string = Samba Server %v
> netbios name = Private-99CB412
> security = user
> map to guest = bad user
> name resolve order = bcast host
> dns proxy = no
> bind interfaces only = yes
> #===========================Share definitions================================
> [Public]
> path = /media/Public
> writable = yes
> guest ok = yes
> guest only = yes
> read only = no
> create mode = 0777
> directory mode = 0777
> force user = nobody
>
> [Protected]
> path = /media/Protected
> valid users = @smbgroup
> guest ok = no
> writable = yes
> browseable = yes
>
> [LinuxN]
> path = /media/Protected/LinuxN
> force user = norah
> guest ok = no
> writable = yes
> browseable = yes
>
> [LinuxB]
> path = /media/Protected/LinuxB
> force user = bill
> guest ok = no
> writable = yes
> browseable = yes
> ```

Here is another reference to assist others
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-samba-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to enable smb1 on Windows 10:
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName smb1protocol

and set simple password on Windows user.