# Unable to access Windows 10 files from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 18.04, mount, windows

Dual booting Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10.

I realised Windows files are not visible by default, unlike in the past.

Mounting the filesystem directly doesn't work.

Steps I have tried include [the steps outlined here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038630/access-windows-10-shared-folder-from-ubuntu-18-04/1038770#1038770), for a similar question. The suggestions do not work, because I get the error `mount: /home/a/shared: mount(2) system call failed: Connection refused.`

When I try to access the shared folder by typing `smb://192.168.1.102`, as stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038770/911804), I am unable to do so, because I get the error `Unhandled error message: Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused`.

To reiterate, I already have a folder that I am sharing through Windows Sharing Centre and `smbclient` is installed on Ubuntu. I just cannot connect to it and I can't figure out why.

Any help would be much appreciated. Otherwise I would probably need to switch to a distribution that lets me access my Windows files by default. Thank you.

Comment: You can easily temporarily mount a Windows NTFS partition by opening a `Files` (Nautilus) window, and clicking on the volume in the left pane. For permanent mounting, you'll have to add a mount in /etc/fstab. In EITHER case, you really shouldn't be mounting your C: partition as you'll potentially cause damage to Windows, and it may give errors on the next Windows boot. You can't smbclient to an Windows OS that is not running at the time.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I think i have a similar problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579116/how-to-find-windows-drive-cd-host-is-not-working. and cant find the partition in the files view and cant mount it either.