# How to access a share on a Synology Drive without mounting it

Tags: networking, samba

How can I (on Ubuntu 22.04) access my Synology shares without mounting them.

If I use the Ubuntu **File** GUI tool I see the Synology unit when I click the *+ Other Locations* option. Clicking on  *(File Sharing)* brings up the shares. I can access the files in the shares by clicking them.

I would like to do that from within a bash script?

`ls smb://<synology-ip>/<share>` doesn't work and neither does `ls smb://<synology-ip>`.

While researching the solution I came across [Access Windows 10 Shared Folder from Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038630/access-windows-10-shared-folder-from-ubuntu-18-04).  The solution required one to `client max protocol = NT1` in the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file.

I did that and got the following when I reloaded the configuration file: `lp_load_ex: Max protocol NT1 is less than min protocol SMB2_02.`

This solution did not work for me.  Not sure if it makes the system more vulnerable.

Thanks

Comment: You may find the Synology shares in `/run/user/$UID/gvfs` if you've already connected to them in the GUI (without mounting). I am not sure how to identify/add network shares via the command line, though.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to use cron to copy files from the synology to the ubuntu machine once a month.  If it can't be done I will go the fstab route.

How does File do it?

Comment: Nautilus (the file manager) uses more aspects of the "Gnome Virtual File System" (gvfs) than I have found documentation for. Generally for this kind of thing I use mounts. If it's a monthly thing, then you could write a shell script that temporarily mounts the network location, copies files, then unmounts on completion.